# No output when I run a javascript code in vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I downloaded node.js and code runner on vs code. The first time I ran the code there was an output. But when I created a new file and tried to run this piece of code in vs code, there wasn't any output. Normally, there should be an output of "1euro" but there is nothing. What's the problem?[picture of how it looks like in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFJY0.png)

```js
var preis=(3);
var rabatt=(2);
var result=(preis-rabatt);
console.log(result+"euro");
```

Comment: You didn't save the file. The big white dot in the tab shows that.

Comment: I dont know if that is the issue, but looking at your vs code you are using comma instead of a dot to declare the 0.5 ...

Comment: Check debug console

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me.. I suggest you to do the following,

1. Save the file.
2. Close the VS code app and reopen it again and run it..

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue it has been resolved by saving the file!